# Redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx

I know that there are a lot of similar questions but I tried several solutions and I can't find correct solution.
I have no idea about nginx. I have only simple task: redirect all addresses `/backend.php/*` to `/backend.php` in one concrete application/website. I used `*` to express anything. Now `/backend.php/*` path is redirected to `/index.php`.

This is my config file:

```
server {
        server_name  _;
        rewrite ^ $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri redirect;
}

upstream md {
        #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
        server unix:/var/run/md.php5-fpm.sock;
}

server
{
    server_name .mydomain.eu .mydomain.du;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

    root /home/md/;

    include conf/restrictions.conf;
    include conf/wordpress.conf; 
    # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Zero-day exploit defense.
        # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
        # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
        # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass md;
    }
}
```

**=======UPDATE===========**

conf/wordpress.conf:

```
# WordPress single blog rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

## Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
#location ~ \.php$ {
#       # Zero-day exploit defense.
#       # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
#       # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
#       # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
#       try_files $uri =404;
#
#       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#       #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#       include fastcgi_params;
#       fastcgi_index index.php;
#       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
##      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
##      fastcgi_pass wp-php;
#}
```

Comment: What's in include ```conf/wordpress.conf``` ?

Comment: I don't see where are you trying to redirect backend.php/* to backend.php. Also, why do you need to rewrite /wp-admin.

Comment: Also, what kind of url are you planning to redirect in your backend? is there a backend.php file? Is there a backend.php folder?

Comment: I enclosed conf file without redirect. I need redirect and I do not know how to do that. I also don't know why there is rewrite /wp-admin. I am not administrator or developer of this. I only have to make redirect in question.

Comment: I suppose that there is backend.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Nginx request rules operate on the regular expressions first from more specific to less specific. Then operate on the non regular expression rules.

In your case I honestly don't know in what order is

```
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

processed so please comment it out while we sort the other issue.

The following rule is the less specific and has no regex, so it will be processed last

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

which is fine. It's a fallback for any request that's not php or either not a real url (for example, wordpress nice urls).

The following rule has regex and is very specific, so it will be processed first than any other and as you see, it affects static files:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}
```

And lastly, the php rule has regex and is less specific than the previous one, so it will be processed for requests that end in .php unless they have a static file extension (which won't happen because if they do, then they won't match the "end with php" thing).

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_pass md;
}
```

So at this point, if you issue a request that points to /backend.php with or without query string, and **there is a file with that name**, it will fall under the .php rule and pass to your php-fpm backend.

If you issue a request that points to /backend.php/something and **there isn't a folder with that name**, it will fall under the first rule, and since there isn't a backend.php folder, it will be redirected (by the try_files directive) to index.php.

Long story short. If you need that urls that have backend.php be redirected to backend.php, you need to set another rule that's more specific than the .php one.

**EDIT: just to discard possible errors, please comment out the line in which you're including conf/wordpress.conf.** Instead, your second server block should read

```
server
{
    server_name .mydomain.eu .mydomain.du;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

    root /home/md/;

    include conf/restrictions.conf;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
           access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location ~ ^/backend\.php/(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri /backend.php?$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass md;
    }
}
```

Comment: where it should be placed? I placed it on the beginning of second server and nginx fails on start.